# How to make a Custom Field available as View Relationship?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to match the data of a field to a contextual value but I cannot find my desired field in the relationships list.

Do I have to something special to this field to get it to show up under relationships?

Comment: Where is your field at? what type of you did you create? Show: Content? Show: comments? or what?

Comment: ******type of view

Comment: It's a field within the custom content type, a drop down with static content.

Comment: perhaps the field is already available? have you tried adding it as a contextual filter?

Comment: Yes, it is available as a contextual filter. But I need it as a relationship

Comment: I'm trying to have a filter that shows content where the name of logged in user is equal to the value of custom field.

Comment: relationships are used when the field in question is in a different entity than the view that you created. For this case you don't need a relationship. I will write an answer in a min.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to have a filter that shows content where the name of
>   logged in user is equal to the value of custom field.

Add your custom field as a Contextual Filter.

Select `Provide a default value` then for Type select `PHP Code`

PHP Contextual Filter Code

```
  global $user; // gets current logged in user object

  if (isset($user->name)) {      
     return $user->name; // gets user name
  }
```